# MySQL query to get records from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I have a master table '`Player`' with '`PlayerId`' as the `primary key`.

I have three tables linked to the '`player`' table. One table may have more records than the other. I need to get all the records for the player in different rows from each table.

PLAYER Table

```
PlayerId int(PK), 
PlayerName Varchar(25)
```

STARTUP Table

```
PlayerId int(FK), 
STARTUPDATE Date
```

REBOOT Table

```
PlayerId int(FK), 
REBOOTDATE Date
```

SHUTDOWN Table

```
PlayerId int(FK), 
SHUTDOWN Date
```

The query as is given below :

```
PLAYERNAME   STARTUPDATE      REBOOTDATE        SHUTDOWNDATE 
PLAYER1      12/2/2015 11:57  12/2/2015 17:30   12/2/2015 20:00 
PLAYER1      12/2/2015 14:57  12/2/2015 15:30 
PLAYER1      12/2/2015 12:30 
PLAYER1      12/2/2015 10:30
```

Comment: Use [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

Comment: You can use join and please specify your table then only we can write the queries

Comment: Is the other three tables have `PlayerId` as foreign key? or what is the relationship key between the `Player` and other three tables?

Comment: Hi Arul,

Yes the other three tables will have PlayerId as the foreign key.

Comment: Hi Arul,

Yes the other three tables will have PlayerId as the foreign key.

PLAYER Table -         PlayerId int(PK),  PlayerName Varchar(25),
STARTUP Table -      PlayerId int(FK),  STARTUPDATE Date
REBOOT Table -       PlayerId int(FK),   REBOOTDATE Date
SHUTDOWN Table -  PlayerId int(FK),  SHUTDOWN Date

The query as is given below :- 
PLAYERNAME   STARTUPDATE  REBOOTDATE SHUTDOWNDATE
   
PLAYER1       12/2/2015 11:57       12/2/2015 17:30   12/2/2015 20:00
PLAYER1       12/2/2015 14:57      12/2/2015 15:30 
PLAYER1       12/2/2015 12:30 
PLAYER1       12/2/2015 10:30

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your expected result, the PlayerId doesn't match with all the tables. In this case you need to use [`LEFT JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/left-join-optimization.html)

```
SELECT PL.PlayerName, ST.StartupDate, RE.RebootDate, SH.ShutDownDate
FROM Player PL
LEFT JOIN Startup ST ON ST.PlayerId = PL.PlayerId
LEFT JOIN Reboot RE ON RE.PlayerId = PL.PlayerId
LEFT JOIN Shutdown SH ON SH.PlayerId = PL.PlayerId
```